# Can someone make my card slider workable by click on arrows?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Hope you are doing well! I want to make my card slider work by clicking on arrows. It is already working when we click next or prev card. but I want to make it work by clicking on arrows too. click left icon to go left or click the right icon to go right card.

Is it possible to make arrows work?

Thankyou for help.

```js
$num = $('.my-card').length;
$even = $num / 2;
$odd = ($num + 1) / 2;

if ($num % 2 == 0) {
  $('.my-card:nth-child(' + $even + ')').addClass('active');
  $('.my-card:nth-child(' + $even + ')').prev().addClass('prev');
  $('.my-card:nth-child(' + $even + ')').next().addClass('next');
} else {
  $('.my-card:nth-child(' + $odd + ')').addClass('active');
  $('.my-card:nth-child(' + $odd + ')').prev().addClass('prev');
  $('.my-card:nth-child(' + $odd + ')').next().addClass('next');
}

$('.my-card').click(function() {
  $slide = $('.active').width();
  console.log($('.active').position().left);
  
  if ($(this).hasClass('next')) {
    $('.card-carousel').stop(false, true).animate({left: '-=' + $slide});
  } else if ($(this).hasClass('prev')) {
    $('.card-carousel').stop(false, true).animate({left: '+=' + $slide});
  }
  
  $(this).removeClass('prev next');
  $(this).siblings().removeClass('prev active next');
  
  $(this).addClass('active');
  $(this).prev().addClass('prev');
  $(this).next().addClass('next');
});


// Keyboard nav
$('html body').keydown(function(e) {
  if (e.keyCode == 37) { // left
    $('.active').prev().trigger('click');
  }
  else if (e.keyCode == 39) { // right
    $('.active').next().trigger('click');
  }
});
```

```css
html body {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}


.card-carousel {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  position: relative;
}

.card-carousel .my-card {
  height: 400px;
  width: 500px;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
  -webkit-transform: scale(0.6) translateY(-2rem);
  transform: scale(0.6) translateY(-2rem);
  opacity: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
  pointer-events: none;
  background: #2e5266;
  background: linear-gradient(to top, #2e5266, #6e8898);
  transition: 1s;
}

.card-carousel .my-card:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  height: 2px;
  width: 100%;
  border-radius: 100%;
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
  bottom: -5rem;
  -webkit-filter: blur(4px);
  filter: blur(4px);
}

.card-carousel .my-card:nth-child(0):before {
  content: '0';
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
  transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
  font-size: 3rem;
  font-weight: 300;
  color: #fff;
}

.card-carousel .my-card:nth-child(1):before {
  content: '1';
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
  transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
  font-size: 3rem;
  font-weight: 300;
  color: #fff;
}

.card-carousel .my-card:nth-child(2):before {
  content: '2';
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
  transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
  font-size: 3rem;
  font-weight: 300;
  color: #fff;
}

.card-carousel .my-card:nth-child(3):before {
  content: '3';
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
  transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
  font-size: 3rem;
  font-weight: 300;
  color: #fff;
}

.card-carousel .my-card:nth-child(4):before {
  content: '4';
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
  transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
  font-size: 3rem;
  font-weight: 300;
  color: #fff;
}

.card-carousel .my-card:nth-child(5):before {
  content: '5';
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
  transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
  font-size: 3rem;
  font-weight: 300;
  color: #fff;
}

.card-carousel .my-card:nth-child(6):before {
  content: '6';
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
  transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
  font-size: 3rem;
  font-weight: 300;
  color: #fff;
}

.card-carousel .my-card:nth-child(7):before {
  content: '7';
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
  transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
  font-size: 3rem;
  font-weight: 300;
  color: #fff;
}

.card-carousel .my-card:nth-child(8):before {
  content: '8';
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
  transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
  font-size: 3rem;
  font-weight: 300;
  color: #fff;
}

.card-carousel .my-card:nth-child(9):before {
  content: '9';
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
  transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
  font-size: 3rem;
  font-weight: 300;
  color: #fff;
}

.card-carousel .my-card.active {
  z-index: 3;
  -webkit-transform: scale(1) translateY(0) translateX(0);
  transform: scale(1) translateY(0) translateX(0);
  opacity: 1;
  pointer-events: auto;
  transition: 1s;
}

.card-carousel .my-card.prev, .card-carousel .my-card.next {
  z-index: 2;
  -webkit-transform: scale(0.8) translateY(-1rem) translateX(0);
  transform: scale(0.8) translateY(-1rem) translateX(0);
  opacity: 0.6;
  pointer-events: auto;
  transition: 1s;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.4.1/css/all.css">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="heading">
</div>
<div class="card-carousel">
  <div class="my-card"></div>
  <div class="my-card"></div>
  <div class="my-card"></div>
  <div class="my-card"></div>
  <div class="my-card"></div>
  <div class="my-card"></div>
  <div class="my-card"></div>
  <div class="my-card"></div>
  <div class="my-card"></div>
</div>

  <div style="font-size:70px">
    <a href=""><i class="fas fa-chevron-circle-left"></i></a>
    <a href=""><i class="fas fa-chevron-circle-right"></i></a>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Post your code in your question for us.

Comment: I have attached this on codepen .

Comment: The link does not work and you're also supposed to put code here, not third party sites.

Comment: Kindly guide me how can i add code here?

Comment: Just edit your question and add in your code. There are also icons on top of the textarea where you type that you can use to format code. The negative votes are because we can't see any code right now to assist and that link doesn't give us much.

Comment: Thanks for guiding me. I have attached a code. Kindly review, please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quick answer: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/dgeaRo

Explenation:
What I did was add a class and an Id to your `a` items and created a Javascript method that mostly does the same as the `$('.my-card').click` function.

This works and should give you a general idea should you want to make changes

Comment: How can I make it in a loop, like if the last slide goes off, start the card slider from the 1st slide?